# I have made some code to do rle compression for multi line RLE of ascii art but the decoder isn't working to decode multi line code

Tags: python, run-length-encoding

I am making a program to do multiline compression and decompression of ASCII art but when I encode something the decoder doesn't work with multiple lines of compressed code and outputs something different.

I have tried inputting the compressed data as a string and  from a file.

```
def encoder(art):  
    codify = ''
    previous_character = ''
    count = 1

    if not art: return ''

    for char in art:
        if char != previous_character:
            if previous_character:
                codify += str(count) + previous_character
            count = 1
            previous_character = char
        else:
            count += 1
    else:
        codify += str(count) + previous_character
        return codify
#The function for decoding
def decoder(data):  
    decode = ''
    add = ''
    for char in art:
        if char.isdigit():
            add += char
        else:
            decode += char * int(add)
            add = ''
    return decode
```

I expected it to output the ASCII image back but it outputted 1000 lines of useless data.

Comment: The decoder loop is `for char in art`, but the input variable of `decoder` isn't `art` but `data`.